# CSS Vertical Line Side Bar

Tags: css

I'm trying to create this vertical line within my HTML page, I wanting to use it as a place to put side information. I'd like to be able to color this as well! I tried a few things, but just can't get it right. Here is my code:

```
#sidebar {
    width: 200 px;
    border-right: 3px solid #000000;
    border-left: 3px solid #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#sidebar {
   float: left; 
   width: 200px;  
   padding: 15px 10px 15px 20px; 
   border-right: 3px solid #000000;
   border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
   min-height: 100vh
}
```

I think this is what you're wanting

Comment: What is the `min-height: 100vh` do?